approximate solution of polynomial equation
I am trying to solve the Following equation for r,
$$2 a Q^4+5 r^4 \left(3 c (\omega +1) r^{1-3 \omega }-2 r (r-3 M)-4 Q^2\right)=0$$
Clearly this is unsolvable. But if we substitute a=0 and c=0, the reduced equation $2 r (r-3 M)+4 Q^2=0$ has one of the solutions $r=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{9 M^2-8 Q^2}+3 M\right)$.. Can I obtain approximate analytical solution of the above equation which gives the same value when substitutions a=0 and c=0 are applied. If yes, then how? I have tried AsymptoticSolve, but got no answer.
Thanks in advance.

No information about the range of $(a,Q,M,\omega)$ ? Are you looking for the samllest positive root ? Please clarify

they are arbitrary constants.

Please, answer the question : are you looking  for the smallest positive root ?

Really sorry for the late reply. I posted this question in other platforms as well and was reading answers there. I am not looking for smallest positive root. I am looking for an approximate analytical solution. I got a way to do that in mathematica. If want to look at it, I can share the post links.

An approximate solution for each possible (real or complex) root ? Yes, please, give me the post links. I cannot resist an equation (even if I cannot solve it).

@ClaudeLeibovici look at this link-https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/303487/solving-a-complicated-equation-for-approximate-analytical-solution?noredirect=1#comment745568_303487

@ClaudeLeibovici Thank you very much. The solution below is a good technic and will be useful for my future works.

Consider $$f(r)=2 a Q^4+5 r^4 \left(3 c (\omega +1) r^{1-3 \omega }-2 r (r-3 M)-4 Q^2\right)$$
Let
$$q=\frac{1}{2} \left(3M+\sqrt{9 M^2-8 Q^2}\right) \qquad \text{and} \qquad r=x+q $$
So
$$g(x)=2 a Q^4+15 c (q+x)^{5-3 \omega }+15 c \omega  (q+x)^{5-3 \omega }+30 M (q+x)^5-20 Q^2(q+x)^4-10 (q+x)^6$$
Expand as a series around $x=0$
$$g(x)=\alpha_0+\alpha_1\,x+\alpha_2\,x^2+\alpha_3\,x^3+\alpha_4\,x^4+\alpha_5\,x^5+\alpha_6\,x^6+\sum_{n=7}^\infty \alpha_n\,x^n=$$ (ask Mathematica for the first coefficients; they are quite simple).
For $n>6$ they are
$$\alpha_n=15\, c\, (\omega +1)\,\,q^{-n-3 \omega +5}\,\, \binom{5-3 \omega }{n} $$ So, we have all of them.
Now, use power series reversion to obtain applying   the explicit formula for the $n^{\text{th}}$ term as given by Morse and Feshbach. So, we know all of them and
$$x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty T_n$$ with
$$T_0=\frac{2 q^{3 \omega } \left(a Q^4+15 M q^5-5
   q^6-10 q^4 Q^2\right)+15 c q^5 (\omega +1)}{5
   q^3 \left(3 c q \left(3 \omega ^2-2 \omega
   -5\right)+2 q^{3 \omega } \left(-15 M q+6 q^2+8   Q^2\right)\right)}$$ Mathematica would provide as many terms as you wish (even $T_1$ is too long to be typed here).
Let me try for the following conditions
$$M=2\quad Q=1 \quad a=\frac 12 \quad c=\frac 14 \quad \omega=\frac 23 \qquad \implies \qquad q=3+\sqrt 7$$ Truncating the initial series to $O(x^5)$, the value of $x$ is given by
$$\frac{3 \left(4722665197252553954364382256292341
   \sqrt{7}-12448487985003546909161704261435037
  \right)}{6714312848201701867006885952179375}$$
that is to say $x=\color{red}{0.0207808}25$
Edit
For the worked example, using the initial series to $O(x^{10})$,
$x=\color{red}{0.020780842619}60$
